# will bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL) generate the same two _id?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-c

Now, I am using mongodb c driver to insert documents to mongodb. Each time, I used the following codes to generate an _id.

```
bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL);
 BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);
```

If multiple applications run the above codes at the same time, will bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL) generate the same two _id with some probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some probability > 0, but very, very close to 0. See the [ObjectId docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for full details of the structure of an ObjectId, but basically you would need two different processes with the same process id to create a document in the same second on machines with the same MAC address and, finally, have them get the same random-seeded 3-digit counter value.